# How to create HTML table with unique name using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am creating a html text box dynamically using javascript and inserting row in table.

Each row in table have three cells (Cell1 : text box, Cell2 : Add new row button, Cell3 : Delete current row button)

Example : Say I created first row and name is given as box1 then i clicked on "Add new row button" and it added one more text box in next row with name "box2". Now I deleted first row by clinking on "Delete current row button", So only one row present with text box name "box2", Now again i clicked on "Add new row button" and it added row with name "box2", So now both text box have same name "box2"

Please help me here, how i can get unique name in such case and can avoid duplicate name for text box.

Here is my java script code

```
function addFieldtest () {
    var myTable = document.getElementById("myTable");
    console.log(myTable);
    var currentIndex = myTable.rows.length;
    var currentRow = myTable.insertRow(-1);

    var sr = document.createElement("INPUT");
    sr.setAttribute("style", "width: 100px");
    sr.setAttribute("type", "text");
    sr.setAttribute("name", "box" + currentIndex);
    sr.setAttribute("value", + currentIndex);

    var addRowBox = document.createElement("input");
    addRowBox.setAttribute("type", "button");
    addRowBox.setAttribute("onclick", "deletekeyword(this);");
    addRowBox.setAttribute("class", "objbutton");
    addRowBox.setAttribute("style", "background: url(../pic/delete.png);width: 20px;height:19px;background-repeat: no-repeat;background-position: center;");
    addRowBox.setAttribute("title", "Delete this keyword");


    var delRowBox = document.createElement("input");
    delRowBox.setAttribute("type", "button");
    delRowBox.setAttribute("value", "Insert keyword");
    delRowBox.setAttribute("onclick", "insertkeyword(this);");
    delRowBox.setAttribute("class", "objbutton");



    var currentCell = currentRow.insertCell(-1);
    currentCell.appendChild(sr);

    var currentCell = currentRow.insertCell(-1);
    currentCell.appendChild(addRowBox);

    var currentCell = currentRow.insertCell(-1);
    currentCell.appendChild(delRowBox);
}


function deletekeyword(r) {
var i = r.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
document.getElementById("myTable").deleteRow(i);
}

function insertkeyword (r) {
    var myTable = document.getElementById("myTable");
    console.log(myTable);
    var currentIndex = myTable.rows.length;
    var i = r.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
    var currentRow = myTable.insertRow(i);

            var sr = document.createElement("INPUT");
    sr.setAttribute("style", "width: 100px");
    sr.setAttribute("type", "text");
    sr.setAttribute("name", "box" + currentIndex);
    sr.setAttribute("value", + currentIndex);

    var addRowBox = document.createElement("input");
    addRowBox.setAttribute("type", "button");
    addRowBox.setAttribute("onclick", "deletekeyword(this);");
    addRowBox.setAttribute("class", "objbutton");
    addRowBox.setAttribute("style", "background: url(../pic/delete.png);width: 20px;height:19px;background-repeat: no-repeat;background-position: center;");
    addRowBox.setAttribute("title", "Delete this keyword");


    var delRowBox = document.createElement("input");
    delRowBox.setAttribute("type", "button");
    delRowBox.setAttribute("value", "Insert keyword");
    delRowBox.setAttribute("onclick", "insertkeyword(this);");
    delRowBox.setAttribute("class", "objbutton");



    var currentCell = currentRow.insertCell(-1);
    currentCell.appendChild(sr);

    var currentCell = currentRow.insertCell(-1);
    currentCell.appendChild(addRowBox);

    var currentCell = currentRow.insertCell(-1);
    currentCell.appendChild(delRowBox);
}
```

Comment: use `box[]` then you can loop though the request variable `box` as an array

Comment: Store the *last incremented value* somewhere and use it for naming the next text box would work

Comment: I tried initializing var currentIndex = 0; outside of javascript function and inside java script function, I am incrementing it (currentIndex ++;), this solves duplicate name problem but introduced another problems.